# Why does Referencing to Array Elements not work in this situation?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, reference

This referencing works:

```
$awesome_array = array (1,2,3);
$cool_array = array (4,5,6);

$ref = &$awesome_array; // reference awesome_array
$awesome_array = $cool_array;
echo $ref; //produces (4,5,6) as expected
```

This referencing also works:

```
$array[0] = "original";
$element_reference = &$array[0]; // reference $array[0]
$array[0] = "modified";
echo $element_reference; // returns "modified" as expected.
```

But referencing the elements in an array does not work when you change the entire array. How do you get around this?

```
$array = array (1,2,3);
$new_array = array (4,5,6);

$element_reference = &$array[0]; // reference $array[0]
$array = $new_array; // CHANGE ENTIRE ARRAY
echo $element_reference; // returns 1 despite the fact that the entire array changed. I need it to return 4?
```

Why does it not return 4 since the array has changed? How do you reference the element so it returns 4?

Answer (score 2):

The reference is *to an element in the array*, and *not* to "an index into a variable called `$array`". As such, none of the references (for elements in the old array) apply to the new array.

The original references still refer to the original array, and elements therein; even if the original array is no longer immediately accessible.

To refer a particular index of a variable that resolves to an array, just use a normal index operation:

```
$array = array (1,2,3);
$new_array = array (4,5,6);

$i = 0;
echo $array[$i];     // -> 1

$array = $new_array; // reassign variable with new array
echo $array[$i];     // -> 4
```